# Estimating magnitude of percentage and absolute error

Tags: homework, analytical-chemistry, equipment

Can someone at least give me a hint to push me in the right direction of how to estimate the magnitude of the absolute and percentage errors when using a smaller amount in mL of a substance for a lab measurement?

Comment: Do you know *what* equipment you were using for measurement? Different pieces of equipment carry different relative errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a small amount of a liquid in mL, you you usually use a pipette. On every pipette, at the top of it, the absolute error is written. As for the relative error, it is the ratio of the absolute error to the measured value. The percent error is the relative error multiplied by 100.